# How to fetch the user saved model form data and return this to the user?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

**Scenario:** A user has already completed a form.

**What's required:** How do you return a completed model form in Views.py? I have followed a few guides on here such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73300246/with-django-connecting-a-user-to-a-completed-form) one with no success. Here is my shortened code containing the relevant sections:

**models.py**

```
APPROVAL_CHOICES = [
    (None, 'Please select an option'),
    ("Yes", "Yes"),
    ("No", "No"),
    ]

class Direct(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.registered_company_name

    class Meta:  
        verbose_name_plural = 'Company Direct Application'

    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    registered_company_name = models.CharField(max_length=250,verbose_name="Company")
    trading_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    registered_company_address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    further_details_required = models.CharField(max_length=3, hoices=APPROVAL_CHOICES, blank=True, verbose_name="Further Details Required")
```

**forms.py**

```
class CompanyDirectApplication(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Direct
        fields = ["registered_company_name", "trading_name", "registered_company_address"]
        widgets = {
        "registered_company_name": TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        "trading_name": TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        "registered_company_address": TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
}
```

**views.py**

```
    if Direct.objects.filter(further_details_required="Yes", user=request.user).exists():
        
        form = CompanyDirectApplication()
        form.instance.user = request.user
        return render(request, 'direct_application.html', {'form': form})
    #otherwise render a blank model form
    else:
        form = CompanyDirectApplication()
        return render(request, 'direct_application.html', {'form': form})
```

The HTML template renders the form with a simple `{{form.as_p}}`. How do I return a completed model form in Views.py to render in my template `{{form.as_p}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) parameter to initialize the form with object:

```
directs = Direct.objects.filter(further_details_required="Yes", user=request.user)
if directs.exists():
    form = CompanyDirectApplication(instance=directs.first())
else:
    form = CompanyDirectApplication()

return render(request, 'direct_application.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the view like this. Its will fill the existing data.

```
if Direct.objects.filter(further_details_required="Yes", user=request.user).exists():

    direct = Direct.objects.get(further_details_required="Yes", user=request.user)
    form = CompanyDirectApplication(instance=direct)

    return render(request, 'direct_application.html', {'form': form})
else:
    form = CompanyDirectApplication()
    return render(request, 'direct_application.html', {'form': form})
```